# Building a temporary `main()` function in c++

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

I'm just learning c++. I have a `main.cpp` unit which has a lot of stuff in it already, and I just want to build a quick little `testMain.cpp` unit that will test a couple of things.

Basically I want to trick the compiler (xCode) into ignoring the real main function for a minute. I could

1. Rename the `main()` function inside `main.cpp` to `mmain()` temporarily.
2. Remove the reference to `main.cpp` in my project temporarily.
3. Comment out the `main()` method in `main.cpp` temporarily.

All these seem pretty clunky. There has to be an easier way. I suspect this is a common thing people do. How do you do it?

Comment: People usually wrap `main` in a pair of `#if #endif` and supply the macro via the command line.

Comment: _There has to be an easier way._ Why? Define easy.

Comment: All your 3 listed options seem pretty easy to me.

Comment: Use [git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) to manage your projects and make a new branch to test new things. If you like them, merge the changes back into your master branch.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to separate the code into multiple files, have most of the logic in one file, have the real main in another and the test main in a third, you compile and link either the first and second or first and third files but never all three together.

Answer (score 0):

Your option 2 is the most common strategie, and from my understanding also the cleanest.

After all, your test application will most likely not share the same command line interface, and that is usually about the only thing which should (of at all) be located in the `main` function or file.

If your `main.cpp` contains significantly more than just the entry point, you should immediately start thinking about how to distribute that logic into the modules you already have.

Answer (score -1):

Use a macro.

### Option 1: Use a macro to include/exclude entire files:

main.cpp:

```
#ifdef USE_REAL_MAIN

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ...
}

#endif
```

testMain.cpp

```
#ifdef USE_TEST_MAIN

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ...
}

#ENDIF
```

build file:

```
gcc -DUSE_REAL_MAIN
gcc -DUSE_TEST_MAIN
```

### Option 2: Use a command-line macro to rename `main`:

main.cpp:

```
int realMain(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ...
}
```

testMain.cpp

```
int testMain(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ...
}
```

build file:

```
gcc -DrealMain=main
gcc -DtestMain=main
```

Note this is probably the least attractive option because it breaks the convention of macros having `UPPER_CASE` names and means the real entrypoint of your program is non-obvious to someone who hasn't seen the build script. It also means the program simply won't compile (as there's no `main` function) without your custom build script either.

### Option 3: Have a new common `main` with the `#ifdef` directives instead:

main.cpp

```
#include "realMain.h"
#include "testMain.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
#ifdef USE_TEST_MAIN
    return testMain( argc, argv );
#else
    return realMain( argc, argv );
#endif
}
```

build file:

```
gcc -DUSE_REAL_MAIN
gcc -DUSE_TEST_MAIN
```

I think this is my preferred option because it's almost self-documenting and makes it clear to another programmer how to get it to work without needing your custom build script.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just compiling from xCode, not from the command line at this stage--taking advantage of xCode's debugger. So I guess that takes away the option of using #3. 

If you know a reason I should just switch to the command line right away, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: Sending someone with apparently little experience in software engineering straight into macro hell is not good advice, regardless of whether the answer itself is otherwise correct in itself. Using macros to alternate behavior requires discipline which even experienced developers often lack, and should only be used if unavoidable. Dead code hidden by a macro quickly becomes just as broken and unmaintained as code archived into block comments.